# vue Array from store is not available (in time) in component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store, lifecycle

In my app I have set of gameCards, stored in the vuex store.

The player fills in a gamepin and the the code checks it, and also gets the gameCards for this pin and stores them in the store and opens the Memory-component:

```
   checkPinExists(){
    
        //this.$store.dispatch('retrieveGameByPin', this.enteredPin)
        this.retrieveGameByPin(this.enteredPin)
        .then(res =>  {
            this.fetchGameCards(this.currentGame.id);  // als spel bestaat de bijbehorende kaarten in de store opslaan
            this.currentGameError = false;    // dus als we hier zijn is er geen gameerror...
            this.checked= true;
        if (this.currentGame.game_status === 'actief'){
            this.$router.push("memory");
        }
        })  
        .catch(err => {
            this.currentGameError = true;
            console.error(err);
        });
      
            
    }
```

The fetchGameCrds is a vuex action:

```
export const fetchGameCards = ({commit}, game_id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {     
        let status = '';
        let data ={};
       console.log("fetching gameCards  ");
        fetch(`api/cardsByGame/${game_id}`)
        .then(async res => {
            status = res.status;
            if(status === 200) {
                data = await res.json(); 
            }
            else {
                data =null;
            } 
        })
        .then(res=>{
            if ( status === 200) {
                commit('SET_GAME_CARDS', data);
                resolve('GameKaarten gevonden');
            }
            else {
                reject('Geen gamekaartenkaart beschikbaar');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

In the Memory-component the cards are retrieved and the game is set up.
Unfortunately I cannot get the gamecards from the store in time.

In the developer pane in the browser I do see that the cards are in the store.

The Memoryscript starts with some debug messages:

```
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
   mounted() {
        
    console.log("at mounted show GameCards:"),
    console.log(this.gameCards);

    this.createDeck(),
    this.createShowCards()
           
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapState([
        'currentSpeler' ,'currentSpelerCard', 'currentGame', 'gameCards'
        ]),
```

resulting in output in the console somewhat like:

```
at mounted show GameCards:

[Handler]]: Array(0)
length: 0
```

Can anyone see how i can solve this?

I do not want to fetch the Cards in the Component itself because I'd like to make use of the gameCards in other components as well without fetching them from the backend each time..

Comment: What version of Vue are you using, and what do your store state and your commit method look like? Vue 2's change detection has a couple of caveats that might cause such issues.

Comment: I am using vue3. Store state : `export default{
    cards:[],
    games:[],
    token:localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
    currentGame:{},
    currentSpeler:{},
    currentSpelerCard:{},
    gameCards:[]
}` and mutations `export const SET_GAME_CARDS = (state, cards) => {
    state.gameCards = cards;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If `gameCards` array is not populated at your component's mount time, you can use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example) to run your functions whenever `gameCards` is actually ready to work with

```js
watch: {
    // whenever gameCards is assigned a new value, this function will run
    gameCards(newValue, oldValue) {
      // only do this after first assignment (when gameCards is initially empty)
      if(oldValue.length === 0) {
        this.createDeck()
        this.createShowCards()
      }
    }
  },
```

The watcher will always run when a new array value is assigned, but as my code example shows, you can control whether or not the watcher actually does anything by using logic based on the new and old array values passed in.

While the watcher by default only runs on complete reassignments of the watched array, you can have it run whenever an individual array object is modified by using a [deep watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers) instead (if that's something you need).